# Add comment box on cart page

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, cart

I followed this [tutorial](http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/magento-add-comment-box-to-each-product-in-cart/):

To add a comment box to each product in cart. The data gets posted but it is never filled into the database. I also have the feeling that the function update items in cart.php never gets executed.

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it,

this was missing in my form

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Comment: I need exaclty this feature for magento 2. Can I apply it?

Answer (score 1):

I have 500 error in order detail page when I'm adding :

```
    public function getItemcomment($item) {
    $itemId = $item->getId();

    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_flat_order_item` o
    LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.quote_item_id = q.item_id
    WHERE o.item_id = $itemId";

    $res = $write->query($query);

    while ($row = $res->fetch() ) {
        if(key_exists('itemcomment',$row)) {
            echo nl2br($row['itemcomment']);
        }
    }
}
```

To app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php